# Tool for database design

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design

What's the best tool for figuring out database design of an already created database on a SQL Server?

I know about Erwin data modeler tool. Not sure how to use it. Do we have to install it on the SQL Server?

Answer (score 1):

IN SQL Server you can click on the "Database Diagrams" node in SQL Enterprise Manager, install the admin tables it asks for, and create an ERD diagrams from the existing tables schema...

Comment: will that create diagram for existing database automatically? I am able to add the tables in the diagram, but how will the relation between tables get generated?

Comment: If you have created Foreign Key Constraints (This is how relationships are represented in a RDBMS), then yes, it will show you those constraints as lines between the tables.  Each line in the diagram (See @Shiva's answer above) represents a foreign Key Constraint which has been created in the database.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **Database Diagrams** in SQL Server Management Studio. [See Designing Database Diagrams (Visual Database Tools)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188251%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

[image]